# c# How to detect first selected/clicked item in OpenFileDialog?

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I am developing a software application using `WinForms`. In order to select multiple files from the `Open File Dialog` browser, I have set the `MultiSelect` property to true. Now after selection, I want to be able to detect which was the `**very first item selected**` from the OFD.

Say, I have selected 10 files (not random) that I need from the OFD list. When I hit OK, probably in a `ListBox` or in a multi-line `TextBox`, I want the first item that I clicked, to be on top of the `ListBox`.

Is there any such in-built method or property to do so? Or any other way to do this? I know I can override the parent class for this functionality, but I thought if there could be another way.